# Using CLR UDTs as SQL Server stored procedure parameters

Tags: .net, sql-server, stored-procedures, clr

I've been doing some reading about CLR integration in SQL Server (I'm using 2008 R2, but I believe this is of little relevance to the question), and bumped into the subject of CLR UDTs. After some reading, I found that most people find them to be evil, advice against using them, and even go as far as suggesting they have no practical application whatsoever. However, every discussion I found about CLR UDTs revolved around using them as column types to store objects in a database, but I couldn't find anything about using them strictly for easing application-database communication.

After having worked on many projects, one of the areas where I still have to find a solution that appeals to me is the communication between the application and data layers, and thus I'm always interested in new approaches. The approach that I usually take is handling all data access through stored procedures. However, there's one thing that annoys me, which is having to maintain the list of an object's properties and the corresponding table columns in many places. For example, if I have an `Product` data object with 20 properties/columns, I have to maintain this property list in several places:

- (1x) database tables
- (3x) create/retrieve/update stored procedures' body
- (3x) create/retrieve/update stored procedures' parameter list
- (3x) application code calling the stored procedures (herein lies the object-relational mapping)
- (1x) data objects class definition

And here's where I see a potential non-evil application for CLR UDTs: using CLR UDTs I could use objects to communicate between the application and the database, and move the object-relational mapping to the stored procedures. Here's an example of what I mean:

Product update stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE crudProductUpdate
    @Product udtProduct
AS
    UPDATE Products
    SET Name = @Product.Name,
        Manufacturer = @Product.Manufacturer,
        Price = @Product.Price,
        ...
    WHERE SKU = @Product.SKU
```

Product update application code:

```
void Update()
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("crudProductUpdate", this.DB)
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Product", this);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Using this approach, I would be able to cut down the places where I need to maintain the property/column list:

- (1x) database tables
- (3x) create/retrieve/update stored procedures' body (herein lies the object-relational mapping)
- (1x) data objects class definition

On paper this almost seems like a no-brainer, but I'm sure I'm being short-sighted and I'm missing some drawbacks to this approach, and potentially useful application of CLR UDTs. So, the question basically is: What drawbacks and/or problems could arise from this approach? Would you recommend (against) using this approach?

Comment: Anyone has any thoughts on the subject?

Comment: "I found that most people find them to be evil" - I guess those people won't be using the `geography` or `geometry` types then, since those are CLR types.

Answer (score 2):

I can see at least two indirect drawbacks:

- It really ties the whole application to SQL Server. If one day in the future, you want to change the persistence layer (for say Oracle, PostgreSQL, MySQL, etc.), you'll have a lot of work to do.
- The integration of the two worlds: OOP vs Relational poses difficult challenges in terms of integration of OOP developers vs DBAs. To oversimplify it, OOP developers don't like SQL, and DBAs don't like C#. So you may have trouble finding the right people with the right Relational+OOP competence, or even the will to tackle it. I personally think it's unfortunate, but that's often the reality in the enterprise world. If you're the only one maintaining the app, that's not a problem.

Otherwise, I think it's a good design choice.

Note you can also use [SQL 2008 Table-Valued parameters with user-defined table types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx) for the same kind of result w/o using the CLR/SQL Server integration facilities.

PS: you could also use code generators for all this, this would cut down the work to do as well.

Comment: seeing this after a year some, +1 for the suggestion of using code generators (NHibernate, LINQ to SQL, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Well if anybody reads this after all this time .....

If your company uses SQL Server, they usually remain with SQL Server, so I think if that is your environment , and likely to remain som then it is a great idea. I have looked at Entity Framework and NHibernate and find them all very convoluted - SQL Server and raw ADO are so powerful with just a few methods , and bouncing a data structure between application and database layers really is a no-brainer with user defined table variables.
The OOP vs DBA mentioned above is complete tosh - if you are developing database driven applications you should understand databases as well as the OO architecture of the application layer, otherwise you have your head in the sand.