# T-SQL Stored Procedure, how to reuse the same insert multiple times - alternatives to sp_execute?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I've spent the last few hours looking for a solution to this, but still haven't found a good one.

My problem is pretty straightforward. I'm writing some very large stored procedures in T SQL (SQL Server 2008 R2) where I have to reuse the same `INSERT` quite a few times within the same stored procedure. The target table has a huge number of columns.

I tried defining a dynamic query into a `varchar` variable. Then executing it with `sp_execute`, specifying all the parameters and it works. But it's not the ideal solution, since whenever I need to call it, I have to duplicate the call with the same huge number of parameters every time.

What I'm looking for is a way to define the `INSERT` to be executed, specifying the variables to be used and then be able to call it with just one line of code, without the need to specify the parameters again.

I was wondering if someone can point me to a more efficient solution in terms of code reuse and readability.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you inserting the same parameter values multiple times? Or are the values changing?

Comment: The majority of them have the same value, only a small amount is changing over time

Answer (score 1):

A CLR user defined type may be a good answer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131120.aspx

You would define a UDT with properties that correspond to your parameters, then you would create a stored procedure (a regular T-SQL proc will work) that takes an instance of your UDT as a parameter and then does the insert, like so:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InsertProc(@params MyUDT)
AS
    INSERT INTO dbo.T1 (a, b, c, d, e, f)
    VALUES (@params.a, @params.b, @params.c, @params.d, @params.e, @params.f);
```

Then you main procedure would do something like this:

```
DECLARE @myParams AS MyUDT

-- call insert with initial parameters
SELECT @myParams.a = 1, @myParams.b = 2, @myParams.c = 3, @myParams.d = 4, @myParams.e = 5, @myParams.f = 6
EXEC dbo.InsertProc @myParams

-- change parameters a and b and call again
SELECT @myParams.a = 10, @myParams.b = 20
EXEC dbo.InsertProc @myParams
```

Comment: I have been looking into the documentation you linked and the creation of an UDT seems like a very tedious task.. Do you have any working example ? i Tried creating a table type (CREATE TYPE T as Table ..) but the syntax for actual usage is very different from what you wrote as example.. I have to use them as a regular tables, insert, selects , etc

Comment: I am not using any table types in my example. Here's some sample code for a UDT: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8s4s5dz(v=vs.80).aspx. Here's a similar discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900420/using-clr-udts-as-sql-server-stored-procedure-parameters

Answer (score 0):

You can create a temporary stored procedure that is tailored to what you need. I think you need to use dynamic SQL to generate the temporary stored procedure. Here's an example [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7ffe2/1):

```
create table T (a int, b int, c int, d int, e int);


create proc InsertIntoT
  @a int,
  @b int,
  @c int,
  @d int
as begin

  declare @procedureContents varchar(max) = '
  create proc #TempInsert 
    @e int
  as 
    insert T values (' + cast(@a as varchar(max))
      + ', '  + cast(@b as varchar(max)) 
      + ', '  + cast(@c as varchar(max)) 
      + ', '  + cast(@d as varchar(max)) 
      + ', @e)'

  exec( @procedureContents)

  exec #TempInsert 1
  exec #TempInsert 2

  exec('drop proc #TempInsert')

end;

exec InsertIntoT 2, 3, 4, 5;
exec InsertIntoT 3, 3, 3, 3;

select * from T
```